# Why is there underline in TextView?

Tags: android

I am adding text from an EditText to Textview:

```
textview.setText(edittext.getText(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

When the text is added, there is an underline beneath the text. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we can add the text to the TextView as follows:

```
textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this:

```
textview.setPaintFlags(mTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
textview.setText(edittext.getText().toString());
```

Or you can use this approach:

```
String test=edittext.getText().toString();
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(test);
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, test.length(), 0);
mTextView.setText(content);
```